# Explain why fork causes the IF condition to behave differently.

Tags: c, if-statement, fork, conditional-statements

I found this sample via a search.
At first glance I thought only the first fork() would be executed based on the IF condition, but actually both fork() calls get executed.
If the fork() command is changed to a simple boolean comparison like (x==10) then the IF conditions behave as expected.

What is it about the fork() that causes the IF condition to behave differently?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
pid_t whichone, first, second;
int howmany;
int status;
int x = 0

if ((first=fork())==0) /* Parent spawns 1st child */
{
    printf("Hiya, I am the first child nd my id is %d\n", getpid());
    sleep(10); 
    exit(0);   
}
else if (first == -1)
{
    perror("1st fork: something went bananas\n");
    exit(1);
}
else if ((second=fork())==0) /* Parent spawns 2nd  child */
{
    printf("Hiya, I am the second child and my id is %d\n", getpid());
    sleep(15); /* Sleep 15 sec, then exit */
    exit(0);   
}
else if (second == -1)
{
    perror("2nd fork: something went bananas\n");
    exit(1);
}

printf("This is the parent\n");

howmany=0; 
while (howmany < 2) /* Wait twice */
{
    whichone=wait(&status);
    howmany++;

    if (whichone==first)
       printf("First child exited ");
    else
       printf("Second child exited ");

    if ((status & 0xffff)==0)
       printf("correctly\n");
    else
       printf("uncorrectly\n");
}
return 0;
```

Here is the output when executed. Notice that both fork() calls are processed.

```
> runtThis
Hiya, I am the first child, and my id is 31204
Hiya, I am the second child, and my id is 31205
This is the parent
First child exited correctly
Second child exited correctly
```

Answer (score 0):

The first `if` detects if its running in the child. If it isn't, but `fork()` didn't fail (i.e., it didn't return -1), it's in the original process, which can then continue and call `fork()` again.

Not sure what the confusion is about.

Answer (score 0):

The `fork()` function duplicates the current process and then returns *in both processes*. So, effectively, the `fork()` function returns twice.

In the new process, `fork()` returns with the value `0`, which causes the relevant branch that prints "I am the child" to be taken.
In the original process, `fork()` returns a non-zero value, indicating either failure (if it is negative) or the process id of the new process (if it is positive). As this value is non-zero, the branch is skipped to the next `else if` and that test is performed until one succeeds.

In the parent process, none of the `if`/`else if` tests will succeed, but each of the `fork` calls causes a new process to be created in which the corresponding test succeeds and that creates the effects you noticed.